# $\frac{d\mu_G}{d\mu_F}$ for $G=F^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F \ge 0$ be the distribution function of $\mu_F$. I could already show that $G:=F^2$ is a distribution function of a measure $\mu_G$ and that $\mu_G << \mu_F$.

Now I need to determine the density $\frac{d\mu_G}{d\mu_F}$. We have never worked with densities before and I'm knew to this notation, is it simplify the fraction of the derivatives or how is this done?

Comment: By distribution function you mean PDF or CDF? If $F$ is a PDF, $F^2$ is not generally one too.

Comment: But if it happens to be, then simply $\frac{d\mu_G}{d\mu_F}=F$.

Comment: $\frac{d\mu_G}{d\mu_F}$ is the Radon-Nicodym derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem

Comment: @Federico Yes it's the Radon Nikodym derivative, but why is it equal to $F$?

Comment: $\mu_G = F\mu_F$ by definition.